# ostream deferencing operator <<

Tags: c++, operators, cout

Why does this work well:

```
cout << "foo";
```

While this doesn't?

```
(&cout)->operator<<("foo");
```

It works fine with numeric values so I guess it's something related to override. (I'm using the MS Visual C++ compiler.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`operator<<` is implemented as a member function for only a limited number of types. For other types, it's implemented as a global overload like:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, T const &t) { 
    // write the data here
}
```

The syntax you used will only work with the overloads that are implemented as member functions, not as globals.

Answer (score 1):

`cout` has an overloaded member function `operator<<(const void *)`. This is the best match for the argument `"foo"`. (`const char*` is implicitly converted to `const void*`.) Thus, a pointer will be output.

```
// These call std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const char * val)    
cout << "foo";
operator<<(cout,"foo");

// This calls cout's member function operator<<(const void * val)
(&cout)->operator<<("foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the output as `cout << "foo";` ,you have to overload the operator `<<`.